# Error `! Undefined control sequence.`using R markdown to create a pdf under MacTex (TexLive 2019)

Tags: mactex, rmarkdown

I'm trying to use R Studio, R version 3.6.3 and MacTex (TeX Live) to create a pdf from a *.Rmd file.

This error came up right after (successfully?) troubleshooting another error message in R itself: https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-rmarkdown-with-tex-live-2019-the-directory-usr-local-texlive-2019-tlpkg-is-not-writable/60310
To solve that earlier problem I installed `kvoptions` with `sudo tlmgr --verify-repo=none install kvoptions`.

My code:

````r
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

Error message:

```
processing file: Untitled.Rmd

/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS Untitled.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Untitled.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter /Users/Jo/Library/R/3.6/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Users/Jo/Library/R/3.6/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
output file: Untitled.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \ifnum 0\ifxetex
                      1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Untitled.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Untitled.log for more info.
```

Untitled.log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.4.8)  8 APR 2020 22:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Untitled.tex
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen103
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 223.
\uproot@=\count89
\leftroot@=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 385.
\classnum@=\count91
\DOTSCASE@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 482.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 485.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 606.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box27
\strutbox@=\box28
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 729.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 730.
\macc@depth=\count93
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count94
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count95
\dspbrk@lvl=\count96
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count97
\column@=\count98
\maxfields@=\count99
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2844.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2845.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, 
and LuaTeX
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \ifnum 0\ifxetex
                      1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1127 strings out of 492616
 12976 string characters out of 6129482
 72427 words of memory out of 5000000
 5101 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,0n,27p,233b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Untitled.tex:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering

\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.5em}}

\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

Thank you so much! I'm quite lost with this

Comment: @Fran Thanks for your reply! I do have `iftex` installed, which should support the code? Or so I thought...

Comment: @Fran where do you get that? It is clearly listed in the log.

Comment: This compiles just fine on my TeXLive 2019 frozen. Did you fully update your mactex after installing it? MacTeX is a convenient snap shot that is easy to install. But the 2019 version you have here is from last Spring, there has been many updates since then.

Comment: Sorry, I really wanted to say `ifxetex`. In the code there are a `\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}` but both are now part of `iftex`; That is, the LaTeX template of pandoc has not been updated accordingly to produce `\usepackage{iftex}`. Options: (1) Modify the template, or  (2) edit the latex export or (2) install ifxetex and ifluatex.

Comment: @daleif I reinstalled my MacTex after encountering this error, it was fully updated beforehand... Thanks for catching that, I'll update all packages and then correct the post above. @Fran I thought iftex supports `\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}` as a legacy mode, even tho it is discredited? That's how I understood the log file anyway...

Comment: A long with `iftex`, `ifxetex` and `ifluatex` are also installed but are now dummies loading `iftex` so old code still works. There has been a lot of fiddling with those packages so I'm guessing your MacTeX was in some bad state an update or forced `iftex` reinstall easily could have fixed.

Comment: It works now! ;; Thanks guys, thanks a lot! It seems my MacTex-installation was somewhat corrupted, I guess?

Comment: @pineappleburger Some time ago with Linux I also had this problem, `iftex` supplied the commands but not  the packages names for some reason. However, now  I have the  legacy packages under iftex directory, so I cannot reproduce the error.